# Read Hotmail emails via Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to read my hotmails using graph explorer.

I go to:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
I login using my hotmail.  I click Get my profile. My profile is returned as expected.
I click Get my mail and get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Posting answer in case anyone wants it.  You need to add the permissions on the messages API.